# How to grey out in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I try to create html tables,I wonder How I can `greyout` unseected cells.

When I click cell `2`,my desired result is like below.

[image]

I tried like below code. If there is more sophisticated method for `greyout` Please let me know.

Thanks

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('table').toggleClass('greyout');
})
```

```css
td {
  background-color: aqua;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.greyout {
  opacity: 0.2;
  /* Real browsers */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the class to all cells *except* the one which was clicked, so use the `not()` method. Also note that to enable subsequent clicks you need to remove that class from any `td` elements before adding it to the next set.

In addition note that `preventDefault()` is redundant on a `td` click handler as there is no default action to prevent. Also, if you want to alias `$` use the argument in the document.ready handler.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $td = $('td').on('click', function() {
    $td.removeClass('greyout').not(this).addClass('greyout');
  })
});
```

```css
td {
  background-color: aqua;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.greyout {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like the caching of td

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the following logic:

```js
$mainTable = $('table');
$mainTable.on('click', 'td', function(){
    if( this.classList.contains('selected') ){
        $(this).removeClass('selected')
    } else{
        $mainTable.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected')
    }

    $mainTable.toggleClass('withSelectedOption', $mainTable.find('.selected').length !== 0);
});
```

```css
table td{
    background: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
}
table.withSelectedOption td{
    background: grey;
}
table.withSelectedOption td.selected{
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```